# Insert loading ring in the splash screen

Tags: android, xamarin, loading, splash-screen

I followed Microsoft tutorial on how to make a splash screen in xamarin.android, and it works properly. Now I would like to insert a progress ring under the bitmap. I've tried different approaches but i can't seem to find the right way to do it

This is the splash screen code:

splash_screen.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>

  </item>

  <item android:left="20dp">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@mipmap/coronamap_bianco"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

splash style in resources > values > styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>  
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>  
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#304057</item>
  </style>
```

SplashActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        }

        // Launches the startup task
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
            Finish();
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**

Since the constraint layer didn't work, I tried to simplify it using a linear layout. As output I get a white screen.

SplashActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashLayout);

        }

        // Launches the startup task
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
            Finish();
        }   
    }
```

SplashLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_splash_screeen"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/coronamap_bianco" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Output: [splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvPIW.jpg)

Comment: Hi, Please go through this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/oussamaalrifai/xamarin-forms-android-workaround-for-splash-screen-with-lo/

Answer (score 2):

You can create a layout for the splash screen , in that layout create an image and a loading circle

splash_screen.xml activity code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_splash_screeen"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_logo" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_splash_screeen" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In your activity, OnCreate set that layout 
SplashActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

      // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.splash_screen);
        }

     .....
      ...

    }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'm having issues with constraint layout, I tried to use a linear layout instead but set content view does not work. The layout doesn't show up at all, there's just a white background.

Comment: the given code is working fine I test it in a real device

Comment: Do I have to modify MyTheme.Splash?

Comment: It didn't work anyway. Since the constraint layer didn't work, I tried to simplify it using a linear layout, check out the edited question

Comment: change xml  extension to xaml

Comment: It works fine but it defeats the purpose because the layout takes too long to load and when it's finally displayed, the splash screen is gone and the actual application is ready to start.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/splashscreen) , we can create a `.xaml` layout for **SplashActivity**. Then can achieve that .

**Splashlayout.xaml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Used in **SplashActivity** :

```
//public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
//{
//    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
//    Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
//}

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Splashlayout);
}
```

Here not forgettingn to modify in `style.xml` :

```
  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>  
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>  
  </style>
```

Then effect as follow :

[image]

Here is [the modified sample link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4w67iarvz096it/Xamarin_Android___Creating_a_Splash_Screen1.rar?dl=0) for reference .

Comment: It works fine but it defeats the purpose because the layout takes too long to load and when it's finally displayed, the splash screen is gone and the actual application is ready to start.

Comment: @AsiaPiazza Yeah , that's the disadvantage . If good solution with `layer-list` will update here later.

Comment: @AsiaPiazza I have checked that , if `Activity` using `style` with `layer-list` can not achieve a animation in `Activity`  . I think that's the limitation of `style` that only can show a static view . If wants a animation or video in activity , you will need to `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Splashlayout)` :-)